# strict string to int[long]

Tags: c++

Do we have a standard way of converting a char* to int (or long) in a strict way, i.e. we should get proper result only if all characters are digits and can fit in an int (or long) -- some way by using strtol etc.. ?

Thus "sbc45", "4590k", "  56", "56 ", should be all invalid using that function.

Comment: What about the `+` and `-` sign prefixes? They are not digits. Are they valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a version close to what @GMan did, but it doesn't accept precedding spaces. e.g. `" 101"`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <exception>

long strict_conversion(const std::string& number_string)
{
    long number;
    std::stringstream convertor;
    convertor << std::noskipws << number_string;
    convertor >> number;
    if( convertor.fail() || !convertor.eof() )
        throw std::runtime_error("The string didn't pass the strict conversion!");
    return number;
}
```

After one minute, here is the generic one:

```
template <typename NumberType>
NumberType strict_conversion(const std::string& number_string)
{
    NumberType number;
    std::stringstream convertor;
    convertor << std::noskipws << number_string;
    convertor >> number;
    if( convertor.fail() || !convertor.eof() )
        throw std::runtime_error("The string didn't pass the strict conversion!");
    return number;
}
```

Comment: Was just about to post that. :)

Comment: Man, you should edit your answer to include that. This is just a tiny issue, don't delete it :)

Comment: using namespace std is fail, especially in essentially copy-and-paste code. You should always use std:: prefix.

Comment: @Arak: Thanks. I didn't mean to come across like I realized that I did, reading my comment. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strtol` - it returns the pointer to the first "error character" in input, so you can just check it for `'\0'` to see if there is any garbage at end or not. If value is out of range, `errno` is set to `ERANGE`, so you can detect that, too.

The only caveat is that `strtol` will quietly discard any leading whitespace. You can check for that yourself by applying `isspace` to the first char of input.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd use something like this:

```
long convert(std::string const &s) { 
    if (s.find_first_not_of("0123456789") != std::string::npos)
        throw std::invalid_argument("Cannot convert value");
    return strtol(s.c_str(), NULL, 10);
}
```